# How to compute big O time complexities for Machine Learning and Deep Learning models? Are there also other measures to define complexity of models?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-complexity, computer-science

I am trying to measure the complexities of ML model implementations as a way of comparing them with statistical approaches (for example). Is it possible to use Big O complexity measures as it is done in other algorithms/programs?

I have [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53385033/1630046) suggestions to measure complexity based on **memory usage** or **training time**. However, these are not theoretical measures and may vary from machine to machine. One approach I use is simply to compare the total number of **trainable parameters**. Probably one needs to measure the total number of **mathematical operations**. However, this could be complex when building deep models with different layer types.

**Do you have suggestions on how to measure the complexity of machine learning models? To be specific one can consider, say a Convolutional Neural Network.**

Answer (score 2):

According to [this source](https://kasperfred.com/series/introduction-to-neural-networks/computational-complexity-of-neural-networks), the big O for backpropagation is O(n^5) and for forward propagation O(n^4)" for feed forward neural networks.

You may consider [this other source](https://www.quora.com/Why-dont-we-talk-about-big-O-for-machine-learning-algorithms) as well that say that:
"Doing a big O analysis on ML algorithms comes down to answering the following questions:

1. Does the ML algorithm converge? If yes, does it converge deterministically or probabilistically?
2. Can the number of iterations required to converge be shown as a function of N? and under what conditions?
3. If we cannot give an explicit form for number of iterations, can we at least provide Rate of convergence?"